# Why is $H_{2}(E,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$ for an elliptic curve $E$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, elliptic-curves

In my script on a course in Modular forms it says that for any (nonsingular) elliptic curve (or torus, for that matter) $E$ the $2$nd homology group $H_{2}(E,\mathbb{Z})$ is equal to $\mathbb{Z}$. Why is that the case? In my opinion, it should be $\mathbb{Z}^{2}$.

Comment: You are right.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Really? I've been wrong on cohomology issues before.

Comment: Oops, I am wrong. I mean $H_1 (E, \mathbb Z)$ is $\mathbb Z^2$, but $H_2 (E, \mathbb Z)$ is $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: $H_0(T)\cong \Bbb Z$, $H_1(T)\cong \Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z$ and $H_2(T)\cong \Bbb Z$ for the torus $T$.

Comment: Because they’re orientable (every complex manifold is.)